# kafka-connect distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to start kafka-connect using:

```
connect-distributed /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties
```

, but then I get:

```
[2017-02-15 12:45:35,962] INFO Instantiated task mysql-adventureworks-source-0 with version 3.1.2 of type io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:264)
[2017-02-15 12:45:35,963] ERROR Failed to start task mysql-adventureworks-source-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:280)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing Schema registry url!
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:64)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:757)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startWork(DistributedHerder.java:750)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.handleRebalanceCompleted(DistributedHerder.java:708)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:174)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The schema url is presented. I've also tried to start it using:

```
connect-distributed /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties
```

, which uses the json format, but I get the same error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like the error is upon startup of a connector task not the worker itself. What are you sending for a connector configuration? Otherwise, maybe post your properties file?

Comment: did you try starting Kafka Connect distributed mode using the out of the box properties file?

`bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties`

Comment: connect-distributed.properties file contains below properties :                                                                                             key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081                                                          If you are using "key.converter" as AvroConverter and not given "key.converter.schema.registry.url" and similarly for value. This issue can occur.

Answer (score -1):

Please start Schema registry service pointing to the right property file. It should work.